# MathJax not working if loaded from local js file or if the source code is included

Tags: html, javascript, mathjax, mathml

I am testing the MathJax javascript library in a local HTML file. It works and correctly renders math formulas if I include:

```
script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'
```

in the HTML file, but it doesn't work if I include instead:

```
script type="text/javascript" src="/path_to/mathjax.js"
```

or even if I put the entire javascript source code. 
What is the reason? I need to load mathjax.js from local js file into a local HTML file, so the first way doesn't help me.
(EDIT- I see an error: `failed to load /extensions/MathZoom.js`)

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 12):

I had to load the entire MathJax distribution (17 Mb zip file), expand it and put the right configuration string in the HTML file. The final form is:
    script type='text/javascript' src='/path_to/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML,local/local'

Comment: See this [MathJax Documentation Page](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/wiki/Shrinking-MathJax-for-%22local%22-installation) for details about how to reduce the MathJax installation for use locally.

Answer (score 5):

This may occur due to two reasons

**1.You may have not extracted the entire zip folder, so first do that.**

Still you are getting the error look into second reason.

2.**You are not referring to the file correctly.** 
eg:

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src="pathto\mathjax.js">
```

You have typed an incorrect filename. Correct name of file is MathJax.js.Given below is the correct way.

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src="pathto\MathJax.js">
```

MathJax.js is the name of the file in the extracted folder(unless modified)

**If all of this is not working,then link to the script in this way:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Pathto\MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
```

The reason that your script is not working is you are not including:

> '?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'

Comment: Thanks, it works for me
but i face another problem(I use a repeater to show a list of mathematic phrase) in first page it works normally but when you change repeater page MathJax not work and show a simple text.

Comment: @AliAmini, make sure the repeater page u mentioned has the mathjax script.Also check your browser console to check for errors.

Comment: thanks for answer, i solved it by adding MathJax.Hub.TypeSet() in repeater page change event(MathJax.Hub.TypeSet() this will run agian MathJax in page)